# What is the dimension of $A-B$, where $B$ is a subspace of $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-geometry, proof-verification, algebraic-curves

My question is really simple, what is the dimension of $A-B$, where $B$ is a subspace of $A$? this space is well-defined? I found this space in this [paper](http://libgen.org/scimag/get.php?doi=10.1007%2Fbf02568416) on page 440:

[image]

Following my calculations in the paper, we would have $\dim(A-B)=\dim(A)-\dim(B)$, is that right? if not, maybe the author made a confusion and he should have written $\dim(\Omega^3(2D)/W)$ instead of $\dim(\Omega^3(2D)\setminus W)$?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your link to the paper does not work for me.

Comment: @KReiser please try again, the link is fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $B$ is a subspace of $A$, then $A-B$ is not in general a vector space, so $\dim(A-B)$ is not well-defined. For example,
$$B=\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}=\{(x,0):x\in\mathbb{R}\}$$
is a subspace of $A=\mathbb{R}^2$, but
$$A-B=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y\neq 0\}$$
is not a vector space.

In fact, it is never a vector space because $0\notin A-B$.

Comment: not only is it not in general a vector space, the difference is *never* a vector space.

Comment: Great answer, thank you.

Comment: So the author made a mistake?

Comment: @user42912 I think that his notation "$\backslash$" just does not mean "set difference" but something else. But it is hard for me to tell what he meant without more context.